# Get all available persistence-unit names defined in persistence.xml

Tags: java, xml, jpa

I have persistence.xml as below (just an example) and I want to retrieve set of all persistence-unit names. In this example **a,b and c**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0">
   <persistence-unit name="a">
   </persistence-unit>
   <persistence-unit name="b">
   </persistence-unit>
   <persistence-unit name="c">
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: JPA doesn't do that. Just get an XML parser and parse it out

Answer (score 0):

You can get all persistence unit names using this code.

```
List<ParsedPersistenceXmlDescriptor> persistenceUnits = PersistenceXmlParser.locatePersistenceUnits(new Properties());
    for (ParsedPersistenceXmlDescriptor descriptor : persistenceUnits) {
        AVAILABLE_MODULES_LIST.add(descriptor.getName());
    }
```

For me it works fine.

Comment: Note that the PersistenceXmlParser is part of Hibernate. So the solution is not applicable to other JPA implementations